# How do I cause this event to occur using the left mouse button instead of the space key?

Tags: python, input, pygame, mouseevent, mouse

I'm currently implementing a feature in my game where a weapon briefly appears in front of the character before disappearing as a means of implementing melee combat. I've been using the space bar to summon the weapon but I'd like to use the left mouse button instead. I have been unable to find how to do that.

Here is the code:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and self.hasShovel == True:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if self.player.facing == 'up':
                    shovel(self, self.player.rect.x, self.player.rect.y - TileSize)
                    
                if self.player.facing == 'down':
                    shovel(self, self.player.rect.x, self.player.rect.y + TileSize)
                    
                if self.player.facing == 'left':
                    shovel(self, self.player.rect.x - TileSize, self.player.rect.y)
                    
                if self.player.facing == 'right':
                    shovel(self, self.player.rect.x + TileSize, self.player.rect.y)
```

I would assume I need to use pygame.mouse.get_pressed(), which I did by removing the "if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE" and instead of having "pygame.KEYDOWN" I did "pygame.mouse.get_pressed()" but that did not do anything. The code still ran but the weapon was absent.

In conclusion, how do I use left mouse button input to execute the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `pygame.KEYDOWN`, use `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`. You also have to change `event.key == pygame.K_SPACE` to `event.button == 1`. Other mouse actions are:

```
1 - left click
2 - middle click
3 - right click
4 - scroll up
5 - scroll down
```

If you need the mouse position, you can get it with `event.pos`.
Other event information can be found at the [pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/index.html)